# How should I properly install flashing on this repair I made to the sill joist and plywood sheathing?

Tags: repair, walls, exterior, siding, flashing

In preparation for a stone step/walkway that we will soon have built, a contractor removed our existing concrete/brick steps and found rot underneath our front door. I removed the rotted wood, which was limited to a section of the exterior facing (of a set of 2) 2x10 sill joists and the plywood sheating attached to it. I replaced both the sill joist and sheathing and now need to add flashing, cedar siding, and some trim pieces around the door. Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to install the flashing here? In particular, I'm not sure how to deal with that hole under the vertical piece of trim next to the door (shown in the right side of the 2nd pic). Note that there will be two pieces of wood trim that cover that, that will extend below the doorway.

I've read lots of articles and watched a bunch of videos on flashing but none of them have been quite applicable to this specific situation. I want to make sure I do it well so that I don't have a repeat of the water damage that necessitated this repair in the first place. I have both aluminum roll flashing (in 10" and 14" lengths) and Zip Tape.  Thanks!

Comment: Flashing the wall should be pretty straight forward. That hole gets covered by coil, that's stuck 2" up in, and behind, w/e you pull away but don't remove. - "rot underneath our front door" because the door isn't flashed. You have to pull the threshold of the door (which is supported by foam?) and put sill tape over your flashing. Pull the whole door package and start over.

Comment: "a bunch of videos on flashing but none of them have been quite applicable to this specific situation" - that's because you can't flash a RO for a door with a door frame in the way.

Comment: The only way to make money doing rehab is to get it as close to new-construction as possible. The videos you should be watching are how to flash a wall, how to flash a door frame, and how to remove and then re-install a door.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Removing the door is not an option for me at the moment but I did my best with the materials I have. It seems at least as good as it was before, which I'll have to settle for for now.